# .ipa crashes on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, itunes, xcode4.6

If I create .ipa file from Xcode with the correct steps, .ipa file crashes on iPad.
But I use .app file under product folder and drag that app file on iTunes it gets converted into .ipa file then it works fine.
I am not getting a problem why this happens.
Please share your suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: crashes means? app starts running and then crashes OR app doesn't even load? Please explain

Comment: Are you able to install app in iPad ?

Comment: How -exactly- do you create the ipa when it does not run. And how do you install it then?

Comment: @Lithu : App get install, but after some navigations it will crash

Answer (score 2):

After Sync with iTunes, You can find crash reports on your device at `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/YOUR iPad/`, which will give you some informations.